# Do Google Apps SMTP servers automatically sign messages with DKIM?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, google-apps, dkim

I've configured my Google Apps account to sign messages with my DomainKey (DKIM), and I've confirmed that the signing takes place and works correctly when I send mail directly from my Google Apps account.

Now, I want to combine that with my web applications that send email through the same domain using Google's SMTP servers. Here's the only issue I see: **do Google's SMTP servers automatically sign the messages I programmatically send from my Google Apps account with DKIM, or do I have to do that manually?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My testing has revealed that **they do** automatically sign messages that are sent through their SMTP servers.